# Azure AD Provisioning Issue

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have setup Provisioning for ON-Prem SCIM application. Azure AD provisioning is not kicking off the provisioning to SCIM application on Create/Update/Delete. Any pointers on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message when you click on the "Test Connection" button in the Provisioning window? https://i.imgur.com/qxrTbfH.png

Comment: There is no error message. Also when I click on Test Connection, a test call is made to the SCIM application

Comment: Are you still looking for help with this question?